# How to access parent model fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['image']
    template_name = 'accounts/my_account.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Accounts:my_account')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

I want to access the first_name, last_name, email properties of the User model.
I am getting error if I user those fields in views.

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What error do you get? Shouldn't the `get_object` here return `self.request.user.userprofile`?

Comment: If I add "self.request.user.user_profile" then it throwing me this error:'User' object has no attribute 'UserProfile'.

Comment: I'm new to Django. I am able to see only one image field on my profile edit page. I want image along with first_name, last_name, email fields from User model too. How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry `.userprofile`. Furthermore if not all your `User`s have a `UserProfile`, this can also result in a lot of errors.